# How to set current time from inside player.on("canplay") method

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to dynamically set the src of video js and start the video from a specific time. The src gets set correctly but my player.currentTime starts an infinite loop for some reason because of which the player gets stuck. Below is my code

```
setVideoTimeToEDLTag = () => {
        let edl_tag_start_time = this.props.collection_edl_reducer.selected_collection_edl_tag.time


    myPlayer.src({type:"video/mp4", src: this.props.collection_edl_reducer.selected_collection_edl_tag.asset_version.video.file}, ()=>{
        console.log("callback")
    });
    myPlayer.on('canplay',  ()=>
         myPlayer.currentTime(edl_tag_start_time) //this creates problem. It initiates an infinite loop
    );

    console.log(edl_tag_start_time)
}
```

Everything else like .play() works well inside 'canplay" method

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if you change the time of the player, the event is triggered again as the description says:

> The canplay event occurs when the browser can start playing the
>   specified audio/video (when it has buffered enough to begin).

So each time you set the time, it may buffer and fire the event again.

Comment: Yes. You might be right. But where to set the initial start time then

Comment: You can try canplaythrough event. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp

Comment: That will also give the same result as per it's definition. right?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing the same problem, I resolved it by reinitializing the player. I used .dipose() method and reinitialized the player and used player.on('ready') method to set the start time.

Here is my code

```
  setVideoTimeToEDLTag = () => {
        videojs('video-el').dispose()
        let edl_tag_start_time = this.props.collection_edl_reducer.selected_collection_edl_tag.time

        const options = {
            fluid: true,
            preload: "auto",
            autoplay: false,
            controls: true,
            aspectRatio: "16:9",
            loop: false,
            playVideo: false
        }

        let videoDiv = document.getElementById('video-container');
        let video = document.createElement('video');
        let source = document.createElement('source');
        video.id = "video-el";
        video.className = "video-js video-el vjs-big-play-centered vjs-default-skin";
        source.setAttribute('src', this.props.collection_edl_reducer.selected_collection_edl_tag.asset_version.video.file);
        video.appendChild(source);
        videoDiv.appendChild(video);

        this.initVideoJS(this.props.collection_edl_reducer.selected_collection_edl_tag.asset_version.video.file, this.props.collection_edl_reducer.selected_collection_edl_tag.time)
}

initVideoJS = (src, time) => {
        let self = this;
        let that = this;
        const options = {
            fluid: true,
            preload: "auto",
            autoplay: false,
            controls: true,
            aspectRatio: "16:9",
            loop: false,
            playVideo: false
        }


        myPlayer = videojs('video-el', options, ()=>{
            myPlayer.currentTime(time)
        })

        this.setState({player: myPlayer})

        myPlayer.play()


    }
```